# Transfer data from ios to Windows Ce device via Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-ce, ios-bluetooth

A newbie to bluetooth.............I would like to send small data, say a string of words from my ios device (iphone/iPad) to a windows ce device via bluetooth. I have a bluetooth csr 4.0 dongle that I have installed on my windows ce device. Right now it does discover and pair with an android device but not an ios device. I know apple has some restrictions on its bluetooth and does not allow file transfer and only talks to some specific bluetooth profiles. But is there any other approach to establish this communication without registering into the apple's  MFI program?

Comment: You can use Core Bluetooth on iOS to exchange data with another BLE/BT4.0 device using the GATT profile. This means you need an app on iOS and a program running on the Windows side with one acting as the central and the other acting as a peripheral.

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11